# Simplification of squared dot product

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $a=[a_1,\ldots,a_m]^T$ and $b=[b_1,\ldots,b_m]^T$ be two $m$-dimensional vectors in $\mathbb{R}^m$.

I have this summation:

$$\sum_{i=1}^m~a_i^2b_i^2$$

My goal is to find a function $f$, such that:

$$\sum_{i=1}^m~a_i^2b_i^2\approx f(a^Tb,a^Ta,b^Tb)=f(\sum_{i=1}^m~a_ib_i,\sum_{i=1}^m~a_ia_i,\sum_{i=1}^m~b_ib_i)$$

(If there is an exact $f$, then it is super-fantastic!)

Is that possible at all?

My try:

Let $e_i$ be the $i$th standard basis vector (i.e., vector of all zeros, except the $i$th dimension is one). Then, $a_i=e_i^Ta=a^Te_i$, so we have:

$$\sum_{i=1}^m~a_i^2b_i^2=\sum_{i=1}^m~e_i^Taa^Te_ie_i^Tbb^Te_i$$
$$=\sum_{i=1}^m~\text{trace}(e_i^Taa^Te_ie_i^Tbb^Te_i)$$

$$=\sum_{i=1}^m~\text{trace}(e_ie_i^Taa^Te_ie_i^Tbb^T)$$

$$=\sum_{i=1}^m~\text{trace}(I_{ii}aa^TI_{ii}bb^T)$$
$$=\sum_{i=1}^m~\text{trace}(b^TI_{ii}aa^TI_{ii}b)$$
$$=\text{trace}(b^T\sum_{i=1}^m~I_{ii}aa^TI_{ii}b)$$
where $I_{ii}$ is an $m\times m$ matrix of all zeros except the $(i,i)$th element is one.

I get stuck here!

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can't have such a thing, to illustrate, $a=(1,0)^T, b=(0,1)^T$ has $a^Tb = 0$ and $\sum a_k^2 b_k^2 = 0$, but $a=(1,-1)^T, b=(1,1)^T$ has $a^Tb = 0$ and $\sum a_k^2 b_k^2 = 2$. Hence the function cannot be a function of $a^Tb$ alone.

Comment: @copper.hat, nice counter-example. Thanks! What's if we assume there are no degenerate situations? Does that change any thing?

Comment: I changed the question a little, this is what I really want.

Comment: Same thing: Take $a=(1,0)^T,b=(0,1)^T$. Then $a^Tb=0, a^Ta=1=b^Tb$ and $\sum a_k^2b_k^2=0$, but $a=(1/\sqrt{2},-1/\sqrt{2})^T$ and $b=(1/\sqrt{2},1/\sqrt{2})$ also gives $a^Tb=0, a^Ta=1,b^Tb=1$, but $\sum a_k^2b_k^2=1$.